# Getting error in file(file, “rt”): cannot open the connection

Tags: r, connection, zip, read.table

I am trying to download a zip file from the google patent bulk data website http://storage.googleapis.com/patents/grantbib/2014/ipgb20140107_wk01.zip, unzip the file and read the table. I used this procedure [Using R to download zipped data file, extract, and import data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053833/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-data)

```
setwd("/var/folders/gk/n1wfrbqx6ss4x3vz7qp9lf3c0000gn/T//RtmpG7LUSs")
temp <- tempfile() 
download.file("http://storage.googleapis.com/patents/grantbib/2014/ipgb20140107_wk01.zip",temp)
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "ipgb20140107_wk01.dat"))
unlink(temp)
```

and I tried to set the working directory to the same place as the temporary file similar to what is suggested in here [Getting error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090622/getting-error-in-filefile-rt-cannot-open-the-connection) but I still get the same error message:

```
    Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In open.connection(file, "rt") :
  cannot locate file 'ipgb20140107_wk01.dat' in zip file '/var/folders/gk/n1wfrbqx6ss4x3vz7qp9lf3c0000gn/T//RtmpG7LUSs/file476796049c7'
```

Comment: What does your `temp` file say? mine says `"C:\\Users\\NAME\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\Rtmpeu2ZbY\\file3e6c5162b84"` with the double `\\`.

Comment: @user113156 mine says "/var/folders/gk/n1wfrbqx6ss4x3vz7qp9lf3c0000gn/T//RtmpG7LUSs/file476796049c7"

Comment: There error is cause by the fact that there is no ".dat" file in the zip folder.  There is a "txt" and "xml" file but not dat file.

Comment: #Dave2e is right: Use the following; `temp <- tempfile() 
download.file("http://storage.googleapis.com/patents/grantbib/2014/ipgb20140107_wk01.zip",temp)
data <- read.delim(unz(temp, "ipgb20140107lst.txt"))
unlink(temp)`