# Trouble opening file in Rstudio

Tags: r

This is my code

```
dat <- read.csv("../rawdata/uscrime.csv")
```

and this is the error I am getting

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

why won't it open my file?

I have done this several times in other projects but now that I have started a new project I can't get it to work.

Comment: Are you sure the file is in that location? You are using a relative file path, so it may help to check where your current working directory is (you can do so by entering `getwd()` in the console).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error in file(file, "rt"): cannot open the connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090622/getting-error-in-filefile-rt-cannot-open-the-connection)

Comment: Look at the second answer in the linked post.